# JQuery live search exact match

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, exact-match

I'm using a live search that I modified to run after pressing enter(I have a very large table and it causes the text entry to lag if done on keyUp) and I'm trying to find out a way to make it an exact search instead of just a similar. The reason being I have a column with store numbers starting from 1 to over 7000, if I type in just '1' I get a whole slew of results. I'm new to JQuery and I've tried to play around with it but I feel like I'm getting no where. Any and all help is appreciated.

Here is the code:

```js
$('#search').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).trigger("enterKey");
    }
});

$("#search").bind("enterKey", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    $("table tr").each(function(index) {
        if (index !== 0) {

            $row = $(this);

            var id = $row.find("td:first").text();

            if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
                $row.hide();
            } else {
                $row.show();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: the keyUp problem can be solved by adding some debounce.

Comment: For exact match: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/rz99cxqb/

Comment: @Tushar I've implemented you're suggestion but still when I search for "1" I am getting all of the cells with 1 in them.

Comment: yes since when you are typing keyUp will call the function several number of times, you can add some milliseconds of wait time so that it doesn't fire immediately. And for strict match you can use something like http://regexr.com/3be4m